# HelloWorld.java always says the string is illegal or an error

Tags: java, string

I'm starting to learn java, and of course HelloWorld is the first program. Below is what I have written:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(“Hello, world!”);
    }
}
```

and the error always comes out as this when I use javac HelloWorld.java:

```
`HelloWorld.java:5: error: illegal character: \8220
        System.out.println(“Hello, world!”);
                           ^
HelloWorld.java:5: error: ';' expected
        System.out.println(“Hello, world!”);
                                ^
HelloWorld.java:5: error: illegal start of expression
        System.out.println(“Hello, world!”);
                                 ^
HelloWorld.java:5: error: ';' expected
            System.out.println(“Hello, world!”);
                                        ^
HelloWorld.java:5: error: illegal character: \8221
        System.out.println(“Hello, world!”);
                                         ^
5 errors`
```

Using Terminal on a Mac, used cp introcs (where I placed the file).

Comment: Seems you copy the source code from a pdf.

Comment: That's why copy-paste is evil.

Comment: Try to use `"` not `“`.

Comment: This is not necessarily the result of copy-paste. There is a "smart quotes" feature in Mavericks where quotes automatically get converted from ordinary quotes to curl quotes. See here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120486/quotes-problem-in-mavericks-or-textedit

Answer (score 6):

(“Hello, world!”);

and

("Hello, world!")

Diffence is in java,

```
" ascii value is 34
“ ascii value is 147
```

so, the error will be occurred.

Answer (score 5):

It was a copy paste error. At least type `"` on your own.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(“Hello, world!”);
    }
}
```

In this the “ is java virtual machine takes Circumflex(ô). so, only the error will be occurred. You just replace “ into "(double quotes) the errors will be resolved.

The resolved code is,

```
public class HelloWorld
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Hello, world!");
        }
    }
```

Output:
Hello, world!

Comment: Why you have answered two times?

Answer (score 3):

Your quotes are left quote and right quote (\8220 and \8221 ) characters which are not accepted by Java, it should be single quotes:

```
(“Hello, world!”);
```

and

```
("Hello, world!")
```

see the difference?

Event the stackoverflow code coloring thingy recognizes it differently :)

Answer (score 2):

character double quote `"` doesn't seem to be valid, copy and paste error may be, correct it in a text editor and re try

Answer (score 1):

Just Changes the quotes `System.out.println("Hello, world!");`

Answer (score 1):

The error messages are even telling you where you're wrong. Never try to copy and paste quotation marks.

Replace all the quotes you've copied with accepted quotation marks.

```
System.out.println("Hello, World!");
```