# Decimal Format error - Java

Tags: java, number-formatting

Can anyone tell me why I get an error message on the following code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Labsheet {

  public static void main(String args[])
{
    double number = 1.0/3.0;

    DecimalFormat number_format = new DecimalFormat(“#.##”);
    System.out.println(number);
    String formatted_string = number_format.format(number);
    System.out.println(formatted_string);
}

}
```

The error is on ("#.##"); - syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens. 
I don't understand why this is an error.

Comment: Closely related, possible dup: [HelloWorld.java always says the string is illegal or an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191198/helloworld-java-always-says-the-string-is-illegal-or-an-error).

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you replace

```
“#.##”
```

with

```
"#.##"
```

as `“` which is &#8220 and `”` which is &#8221 cannot be use delimit a String.

Comment: @jay the ASCII quotation mark is acceptable, it is neither left nor right and you can type it on your keyboard easily.  The ones you use are the left quotation marks and right quotation mark which are different unicode character. It might be nicer if Java understood them, but it doesn't.

Comment: I tried testing it (changing the double input) with 8/3 this time but it doesn't seem to work... not that I get any errors but it just displays: 2, as the answer. I assume I need to use different characters/pattern.

Comment: @jay 8/3 is 2 with 2 remainder.  This is integer division which you most likely did in primary school but most people forget when they learn about decimals. if you want decimals, using a floating value e.g. `8.0/3` which will be 2.6666666...

Comment: thanks for the help Yep silly mistake I spotted the error.